# React-Native Passing users email and password to submit button

Tags: firebase, react-native

import FirebaseAPI from '../MyModules/FirebaseAPI';

function submit() {

```js
import FirebaseAPI from '../MyModules/FirebaseAPI';

export default function LinksScreen() {
  const [email, onChangeText] = React.useState('Enter Email');
  const [password, onChangeText2] = React.useState('Enter Password');

  const submit = () => {
    FirebaseAPI.createUser(email, password)
  }
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.wrapper} behavior="padding">
          <View style={styles.scrollViewWrapper}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
              <Text style={styles.loginHeader}>Creat an Account </Text>
              <TextInput 
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                value={email}
              />
              <TextInput 
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                onChangeText={text => onChangeText2(text)}
                value={password}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{marginTop: '5%'}}
                onPress= {submit()}>
                <View>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </View>
                
                
                
//code from FirebaseAPI.js
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

export const createUser = (email, password) => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    
    .catch((error) => console.log('createUser error: ', error));
}
```

//etc

my error is 
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_FirebaseAPI.default.createUser')

I assume its a scoping issue but unsure on how to fix it.  Still new at react. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `email` and `password` are not scope of the `submit` function. You either need to move the `submit` function inside the component function or pass the values to the function

```js
export default function LinksScreen() {
  const [email, onChangeText] = React.useState('Enter Email');
  const [password, onChangeText2] = React.useState('Enter Password');

  const submit = () => {
    FirebaseAPI.createUser(email, password)
  } 
  return (
  ....
  )
```

OR

```js
 <TouchableOpacity
    style={{marginTop: '5%'}}
    onPress= {() => submit(email, password)}>
      <View>
        <Text>Submit</Text>
      </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Also where you are importing the FirebaseAPI import as

`import * as FirebaseAPI from '../MyModules/FirebaseAPI';`

Comment: O wow both of those make sense especially the 2nd my point of view.  Still getting the error though so it must be something with my create user function.  Any idea? I added the code above

Comment: Added a suggestion a the end. Since FirebaseAPI is a module you need to write the import differently.

Comment: okay the error changed to TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.email')  I appreciate the help Mohit

Comment: I don't see and `this.state.email` in the code that you have shared in the post. Are you using it in the `onChangeText2` functions?

Comment: hahah wow I must be getting tired I tried something earlier by diverting to state instead and was without luck and when I was waiting/looking for answers I must of accidentally uncommented the wrong submit button.  had 2 one using state the other not.  Anyhow all good now Thanks a ton Mohit